# Maintaining JavaScript Code in the <Head> after ASP.Net Postback.

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, postback

As the title suggests, I am having trouble maintaining my code on postback. I have a bunch of jQuery code in the Head section and this works fine until a postback occurs after which it ceases to function!

How can I fix this? Does the head not get read on postback, and is there a way in which I can force this to happen?

JavaScript is:

```html
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.tablesorter tbody tr').tablesorter();

        $('.tablesearch tbody tr').quicksearch({
            position: 'before',
            attached: 'table.tablesearch',
            stripeRowClass: ['odd', 'even'],
            labelText: 'Search:',
            delay: 100
        });
       }); 
        </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just have that code hard coded into your page's head then a post back won't affect it. I would check the following by debugging (FireBug in FireFox is a good debugger):

- Verify the script is still in the head on postback.
- verify that the css classes are in fact attached to some element in the page.
- verify that the jquery code is executing after the browser is done loading on post back.

EDIT: Are you using UpdatePanels for your post back? In other words is this an asynchronous postback or a normal full page refresh?

EDIT EDIT:  AHhhhh... Ok. So if you're using UpdatePanels then the document's ready state is already in the ready so that portion of jquery code won't be fired again. I would extract the jquery delegate out to a separate function that you can also call after the async postback.

Answer (score 2):

put your code in

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

    /* code here */

}
```

instead of in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

`pageLoad()` is a function that will execute after all postbacks, synchronous and asynchronous. See this answer for more details

- [**How to have a javascript callback executed after an update panel postback**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152946/how-to-have-a-javascript-callback-executed-after-an-update-panel-postback/1153002#1153002)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the postback pre-empts the page's onLoad event, which jQuery needs to hook into to use it's .ready().

Answer (score 1):

1. Does the script exist in the HTML code after the postback?
2. If so, does the code get executed?  Test by commenting out your code and temporarily add `alert('test');`
3. If so, are the elements referenced by the code available on the page after postback?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(document).ready you should put your code in a function called pageLoad(). The pageLoad() function is by convention wired up to be called whenever the page has a postback/asyncpostback.