# With jquery Watermark, how do I assign it do a yet-to-be-created div?

Tags: jquery, watermark

In this sample, the watermark plug-in doesn't work at first, because the div "tbFirstName" is not loaded yet.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#tbFirstName').watermark('Required information');
});
```

The (.live) Jquery tool or (.on) tool seem to work based on a event such as "click" or "blur". Do you know how I can get this watermark effect on a div that loads in the future, and without having to assign to a user-event?

Many thanks!

Ref:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: when you say *not loaded yet*, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: witch one of the 124332 plugins for watermark are you using? It's always good to point out the link to the plugin you are using, makes things easier for the ones who try to help.

Comment: Why don't you just run the javascript to wireup the watermark when you load the div?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I mean, it is being created on the programtically, not when the DOM is loaded initially. Thanks

Comment: @balexandre Sorry, I didn't realize there were that many jquery watermark plug-ins. This one's called jquery-watermark. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: @Hairgami_Master that's a `input` plugin, why do you mention `<div>`'s?

Comment: @balexandre Because I don't know the difference- I just call every thing a div (as a generic term for node I guess).

Comment: if you doing what you're doing, you should at least know the difference between a `<div>` and an `<input>` no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the `DOMNodeInserted` event:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted','#tbFirstName',function(){
    $('#tbFirstName').watermark('Required information');
});
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BkgBe/).

Note that it's important to attach the `on()` method to whatever element is closest the closest parent to the to-be-attached `$('#tbFirstName')` element, otherwise it will run every time something's appended to the DOM.

It's also worth noting, just for completion, that it'd be far easier, and more efficient, to bind the `watermark()` while *creating* or *appending* that element to the DOM.

References:

- [`DOMNodeInserted` at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html).
- [`DOMNodeInserted` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference).

Comment: Couldn't this get VERY process intensive, since it would attempt this on every element insertion to the DOM?

Comment: Well, obviously attach the event to the nearest possible parent element that's already present in the DOM when the `on()` is assigned. Besides that, I'm not sure how else he could more efficiently accomplish his aim, unless he binds the event in whatever function creates/appends/loads the element. But I sort of assume that something so obvious has been tried and found wanting (for some reason).

Comment: I think doing the binding just before the element is created might be the best call.  But then again, if the OP can do that, why couldn't they just do the binding after the element is created in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas- This did help me realize something. The element is being created by code in a ASP .net project. For some reason, JQuery is not picking up on the element being created... I have another problem to sort through first.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call `.watermark()` on the new inputs creation

like this [example in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ocevat/edit#javascript,html)

```
$(function() {

  $(".watermark").watermark("Write something...");

  $(".btn-add").click(function() {
    $(".list").append('<li><input type="text" class="watermark" /></li>');
    $(".watermark").watermark("Write something...");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks- very clever. I'm going to have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#tbFirstName').live("watermark", function(){ 
            $('#tbFirstName').html("required info");
        });
});
```

Reason, since the element is not present already, the binding does not work. "live" api is used to dynamically bind events to elements.

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Edit : Stephan pointed out that "live()" wouldn't work, I just read the same on your description to, sorry :)

Comment: "watermark" is not an event that live can bind to.   How would this work?

Comment: The closest thing to your example would be a custom event, but you would then need to trigger that event:  http://api.jquery.com/live/#example-3

Comment: Thanks I just realized the element being created is not being picked up by jquery for some reason. I have another problem to deal with first.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem was specific to the ASP.NET Update Panel. A post led me to the right answer, which was to use this:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
    ... 
}
```

instead of the $(document).ready function.

Thank you to all who offered there help- much appreciation. Here's the helpful post:

[How to have a javascript callback executed after an update panel postback...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152946/how-to-have-a-javascript-callback-executed-after-an-update-panel-postback)