# asp.net update panel runs java script calls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have this update pannel

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>  

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>


        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>

     </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This update panel updates each 2 minutes.

I have a javascript functions that fills the data into a `canvas`, I wan this javascript function to be fired each time this update panel updates.

how to do that please?

where should I put the script? **maybe inside the update panel**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find the solution in this thread: [How to have a javascript callback executed after an update panel postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152946/how-to-have-a-javascript-callback-executed-after-an-update-panel-postback)

> put it inside
>        function pageLoad(sender, args) { 
>           ...  }