# Google Map API in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement where i need to use google maps api in my project. I was able to use the api and was able to load the map on my page.

The issue what i am facing is i need to reload the map based on the dropdown control value which contains all the States of India, correspondingly i need to load another dropdown of city based on the state value selected.

The map loads successfully on first request but when i change the value in the dropdown the map does not get loaded.

I have used Update Panel on my page as i need to asynchronously load the city dropdown based on the state selected.

**When i remove the autopostback property of state dropdown the map gets loaded correctly. Its only becuase of this asynchronous call to load the city dropdown is causing a problem.**

Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: This question may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1153002/1211524

Comment: Hey Chad... It worked like a charm !! Thanks a lot..